# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Alamofire Github example

Tags: swift, alamofire

So I have a simple main.swift

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
  print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))") // original url request
  print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
  print("Result: \(response.result)") // response serialization result

  if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
  }

  if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
  }
}
```

When i run this, a got "Program ended with exit code: 0" and nothing more.
I put breakpoint on

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
```

**and saw this -** 
[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

Problem in "responseJSON" method. What I did wrong ? Simple example from Alamofire Github.

Comment: Who can explain to me? I only added this code "RunLoop.current.run()" and it work fine

Answer (score 0):

please add these lines in info.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!-- Optional: Specify minimum TLS version -->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Please also pass Base URl

Comment: I dont have "info.plist".

Comment: Lack of App Transport Security does not crash an app with "Program ended with exit code: 0".